# HTACCESS on PHP or PHP on Python3 SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: php, python-3.x, .htaccess, server

When using the PHP server `php -S` I don't have access to the use of .htaccess files, and thus can't easily create a directory index. However, when using the python3 server `python3 -m http.server` I don't have access to the PHP language. I only need one or the other, but I'm unsure of how to accomplish either which leaves me in a state where neither server works for the purposes I require it to and while I'm aware of services like apache I'd prefer to keep the server access just to my local machine.

Comment: `.htaccess` is specific to apache. You can install apache locally and never open up port 80/set up port forwarding so the access would just be local to your machine.

Comment: make a router script as mentioned [in docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) or use a framework which uses a single entry point router / front controller pattern, which can be used in place of the router script.. but if you have to use .haccess (which you should avoid putting more then one catch-all rewrite in) you need to install apache